# pusher-java-client - no re-connection once the connection is lost on an Android device

Tags: android, websocket, pusher

I am using pusher-java-client (https://github.com/pusher/pusher-java-client) for receiving notification on my android devices - Android Version 4.1.1 and Android Version 4.0.4.

I leave the app running on the device which is connected through wifi to the web (no 3G connection).
The app gets notification but after a day or so, if I have left the app running, it stops to get the notification (also no other interaction with the device during that time).

I have set the device such that the its connected to wifi always. The app may go to the background.

I tried to do a reconnection if I get the Disconnected state in the onConnectionStateChange call back (but that doesn't seem to re-connect).

Any other suggestions on how to restore and keep the connection without closing the app?

Thanks!

Comment: For more on this question, follow these 2 discussions: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-java-client/issues/33 https://github.com/pusher/pusher-java-client/issues/34